# Changing Foreground color of ComboBox CheckBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to change the foreground color of ComboBoxItem, however it does not apply, what am I doing wrong? Also I'm trying to change the foreground color of hovers on ComboBoxItem which does not work as well.

Here is my xaml:

```
<ComboBox Foreground="Yellow"  Name="txtDispatch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,15,0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"   materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Select Dispatch"   SelectionChanged="txtDispatch_SelectionChanged">
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <CheckBox  Foreground="Yellow" Name="chkDispatch" Width="220"  Checked="txtDispatch_Checked" Unchecked="txtDispatch_Checked" Content="{Binding Dispatch.id}"  IsChecked="{Binding Check_Status}"  CommandParameter="{Binding Dispatch.id}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
```

Comment: [ComboBox styles and templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/combobox-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ComboBox Foreground="Black">
                <ComboBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>   <!--Optional-->
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>   <!--Optional-->
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ComboBox.Style>
                
                <!-- Items List-->
                <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>3</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>4</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>5</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
```

Very Simple. Use the style.